# Are default program icons protected by copyright?

Tags: icons

If you look at files in Windows Explorer, a DOC file has it's icon, a PDF, etc.
That is if the application is installed on the computer.

Are these icons copyright protected or can they be use in applications?

Reason is: I want to show a standard "Word Document" icon for a .doc file to the user, even if Word is not installed on the current computer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about copyright / intellectual properties / licensing / legal issues instead of directly about programming or software development.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, the icons are copyrighted, in this case [by Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/about/legal/permissions/default.mspx#EPE).

Comment: > Icons are not to be used as "artwork" or design elements.

I thought that artwork, criticism & parodies are fair use.

Comment: Artwork may or may not be fair use. Copyright law in the locales where the art is being produced / distributed / displayed / etc may or may not have a fair use clause in their copyright law.

Comment: Moreover, Microsoft can write whatever they want about the use of their copyrighted images, but what they write has no power aside from copyright law unless you made an agreement with them.  In particular, unless you've agreed otherwise you can use the icons according to fair use.  "Fair use" doesn't exist in all jurisdictions on Earth, and often doesn't mean what people think it does, so check with a lawyer specializing in intellectual property law before getting yourself in trouble.

Answer (score 7):

[Office icon gallery](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=12b99325-93e8-4ed4-8385-74d0f7661318&displaylang=en)

> Microsoft Corporation (or based on where you live, one of its affiliates) licenses this supplement to you. You may use a copy of this supplement with each validly licensed copy of Microsoft 2007 Office System Desktop Application software (the “software”). You may not use the supplement if you do not have a license for the software. The license terms for the software apply to your use of this supplement. To read the license terms, go to the “Help” menu in the software. Microsoft provides support services for the supplement as described at www.support.microsoft.com/common/international.aspx.

I'm guessing that the same copyrights apply in the standard icons. But that's just a guess...

Answer (score 1):

Not programming related, and IANAL, but yes, they are copyrighted, and you cannot bundle them with your software.

That said, in most cases, the OS *will* provide some default representation. On my computers, I see an open office icon with .doc files.

Comment: It is not about typing code, but it is relevant for program design, so I think it belongs here.

Answer (score 0):

I think yes it's copyrighted, but there are a lot of similar Icons on the web you can use.

[iconarchive](http://www.iconarchive.com/category/application/microsoft-office-icons-by-nelson.html)

[softpedia](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Desktop-Enhancements/Icons-Related/Microsoft-Office-2007-icons.shtml)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the jurisdiction - in most places, Copyright is automatic and doesn't have to be asserted.

In fact you should **always** assume Copyright applies to an image or icon.

Only when there's a statement that copyright is *not claimed* can you assume it's free to use.

I don't know if MS would object to your applying an 'openoffice' icon to one of their Word files.